# Page does not update until refresh it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On **page A**, I use `$.ajax` to get data from **page B**.
When I access to page A, $.ajax cannot get any new data from **page B** until I have to go to **page B** and refresh it.

Any solution how I can access to page A and get new data without going to page B and refresh it?

Thank you.

Page A:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "example",
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(checker) {
        var data = $(checker).filter("#test[data-value='"+something+"']").text();
     $(".content").append(data);
     },
 });
```

Page B:

```
<span id="test" data-value="abcd">This is data 1</span>
<span id="test" data-value="efgh">This is data 2</span>
```

Comment: Show us the relevent code. We can't possibly help you solve a problem if we can't see the problem in the first place.

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: I edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is check that you have disabled the web browser's cache.